# How come the Observer was unable to stop the assassin?

Tags: fringe

In *August **(2x08)***, an Observer named August is seen kidnapping a girl (Christine Hollis), and he just stands there nonchalantly as a police officer fires at him. In *The Firefly **(3x10)***, another Observer calmly disables three armed robbers in a jewelry store. He also catches two bullets with his hands in the process.

August, like the other Observers, seems to be able to tell the future (when he saw that Christine's plane was going to crash). With these and possibly other powers, how come he was unable to stop a human assassin from killing him? Specially considering he was armed with a superior weapon and the human only had a regular handgun?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He was able to.  He chose not to.

From the [Fringe wiki](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/August_%28Character%29):

> The Observer confirms to August that Hollis will now be safe as "you
>   made her important, she is responsible for the death of one of us".

Comment: The things people do for love...